# How can I return only several Json fields of an inner object with Jackson

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jackson

I'm using Jackson + spring RestControlles

Lets say I have 3 classes

```
class Card {
   String id;
   String pan;
   String holder;
   String expiry;
}

class CardProfile {
   String id;
   Card card;
   ...
}

class Recipient {
   String name;
   Card card;
   ...
}
```

So when I serialize a CardProfile object I want all fields of object card to be percent in result json.

But in case Recipient object , Json has to have only part of object card(For example : pan, holder) . 
Is there a way to present Card object in json with different set of fields?

Use of annotations like @JsonIgnore will remove fields from both cases.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking again - is this approach scalable? What if you need something similar again?
Why not rely on inheritance and create a base class and multiple subclasses with attributes you are interested in?

```
class Card{
   // bare min attribute
   .....
}

class SubCard1 extends Card{
   //add more attribute 
   .....
}

class SubCard2 extends Card{
   //add more attribute 
   .....
}
```

Use SubCard1 or SubCard2 based on what you need? Same can be used for other classes. If this is more dynamic - look at design patterns.

Answer (score -1):

when you serialize the object you can keep only the parameter that are interest for you.
I post a simple java code to resolve this stuff you can convert the code in the lenguage that you need.
the following code is prt of the Recipient class which contains two field: `String name` and `Card card`
To write the json object:

```
    @Override
public final void toJSON(final OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    final JsonGenerator jg = JSON_FACTORY.createGenerator(out);
    jg.writeStartObject();
    jg.writeFieldName("Recipient");
    jg.writeStartObject();
    jg.writeNumberField("id",card.getID());
    jg.writeStringField("name", name);
    jg.writeStringField("pan", card.getPan());
    jg.writeStringField("holder", card.getHolder());
    jg.writeEndObject();
    jg.writeEndObject();
    jg.flush();
}
```

to get the the object from the json:

```
  public static Recipient fromJSON(final InputStream in) throws IOException {
        int jId = -1;
        String jName = null;
        String jHolder = null;
        String jPan = null;
        //Obtain a new JsonParser to parse Recipient from JSON
        final JsonParser jp = JSON_FACTORY.createParser(in);
        while (jp.getCurrentToken() != JsonToken.FIELD_NAME || "Recipient".equals(jp.getCurrentName()) == false) {
                // there are no more events
                if (jp.nextToken() == null) {
                    throw new IOException("Unable to parse JSON: no employee object found.");
                }
        }
        while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (jp.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    switch (jp.getCurrentName()) {
                        case "id":
                            jp.nextToken();
                            jId = jp.getIntValue();
                            break;
                        case "name":
                            jp.nextToken();
                            jName = jp.getText();
                            break;
                        case "pan":
                            jp.nextToken();
                            jPan = jp.getText();
                            break;
                        case "holder":
                            jp.nextToken();
                            jHolder = jp.getText();
        break; }
        } }
            //create new card object, the values not present in the json will set to null
            Card card = new Card(jId,null,jPan,jHolder,null);
            return new Recipient(jName, card);
        }
    }
```

I tried to adapt the code for you but it is just to give you an idea,I hope this will be usefull for you.